# Rails set role based relationship between belong_to and has_many for multiple primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My belong_to Item -> User relationship works; however, how do I setup the corresponding relationship in my User model (has many User -> Item)?

```
#item.rb
belongs_to :update_user, foreign_key: :item_updated_at_user_id, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :delete_user, foreign_key: :item_deleted_at_user_id, class_name: "User"

#user.rb
has_many :update_items, class_name: "Items", inverse_of: :update_user
has_many :delete_items, class_name: "Items", inverse_of: :delete_user
```

Comment: ok, I think what I need is `has_many :update_items, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: "item_updated_at_user_id"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associations should look as below:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :update_user, foreign_key: :item_updated_at_user_id, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :update_items
  belongs_to :delete_user, foreign_key: :item_deleted_at_user_id, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :delete_items
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :update_items, foreign_key: :item_updated_at_user_id, class_name: "Item", inverse_of: :update_user
  has_many :delete_items, foreign_key: :item_deleted_at_user_id, class_name: "Item", inverse_of: :delete_user
end
```

---

`class_name: "Items"` should be `class_name: "Item"`(**Note**: Model names are Singular)

Specify `foreign key` option on both side of association.

Also, Its best to specify `inverse_of` option on both sides of association.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you..thank you.. not sure why there's hardly good documentation on the above scenario... I also had to update my item serializer classes with the new role names